# Geotagged wiki data

Tags: wikipedia

For a research purpose how can I extract geotagged wiki data (containing page id or titles for articles that refer to particular geolocation) for a city in England.

Comment: Will pages linking to the city page work for you?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for all pages that have been geotagged with coordinates that fall within the boundary of the city. Thanks

Comment: What magnitude of articles do you expect to work with?

Comment: I first need a list of all the articles that fall within the boundary of my study area (based on their geotags).

Answer (score 1):

Cities only have point geometry, so how do you define the "boundary"? Taking
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Places_within_1_km_of_the_Arc_de_Triomphe_(Q64436) as an example, here are Wikidata entries within 1 km of London:

https://w.wiki/yrX

```
SELECT ?place ?placeLabel ?page ?location ?dist WHERE
{
  wd:Q84 wdt:P625 ?loc .
  SERVICE wikibase:around {
      ?place wdt:P625 ?location .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:center ?loc .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:radius "1" .
  }
  optional {?page schema:about ?place; schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>}
  BIND(geof:distance(?loc, ?location) as ?dist)
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
} order by ?dist
```

Note: without OPTIONAL the query times out, not sure why, posted bug: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T274519